# NodeJS try catch not working in development mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am developing my discord bot, I don't know why this happen, the try catch works in production but not working in development.

Code inside an event listener `client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => { // code below is here })`:

```
let profilePanel = []

try {
  profilePanel = await Promise.all(
    mGenshinProfile.genshinUIDs.map(async gUID => {
      const playerData = await genshin.getPlayer(gUID)
      return await createGenshinProfilePanel(
        interaction,
        playerData,
        userId,
      )
    }),
  )
} catch (e) {
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder().setColor(theme.primary)
  embed.setTitle('Error').setDescription('Something went wrong!')
  await interaction.editReply({
    embeds: [embed],
  })
  await wait(5000)
  await interaction.deleteReply()
  return
}
```

There's **throw new error(...)** in `genshin.getPlayer` function while the server is under maintenance.

Here's how the error info looks like catch from `client.on('error', err => {console.log(err)})`:

```
APIError: Maintenance or everything is broken
    at RequestHandler.player (/app/node_modules/enkanetwork.js/dist/handlers/RequestHandler.js:48:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async GenshinClient.getPlayer (/app/node_modules/enkanetwork.js/dist/client/Genshin/GenshinClient.js:73:22)
    at async Object.execute (file:///app/src/commands/modalSubmit/Genshin/addGenshinProfileModal.ts:101:32)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (file:///app/src/listeners/interactionCreate.ts:40:17) {
  status: 424,
  path: 'https://enka.network/api/uid/824957678'
}
```

However in development it won't catch the error and execute what inside catch. But funny in production it works as expected, the attachment is the proof of it works in production: [production mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKv47.png).

I am using docker image `node:lts-alpine` which is `v20.11.0`

I run my development with this script inside package.json:

```
clear && NODE_ENV=dev && node --import ./register-hooks.js --watch src/app.ts
```

I am expecting the error handler by try catch works in development mode.

Comment: `interaction =>` This is not even marked `async`, so not even sure how your code with `await` is even compiling.

Comment: @Keith ah sorry I forgot to type async here, I have async before `interaction`, I will edit the question

Comment: What does the code look like for `genshin.getPlayer` for both client & server side.

Comment: So what `playerData` does `getPlayer()` return when it doesn't throw the expected error?